# Parsing a Dropdown Option Label in Matrix

Tags: matrix

How do I access the Dropdown Option Label in this matrix?

```
<div class="post-weather">
    {% for block in entry.weather %}
        {% if block.type == "condition" %}
            <span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="{{ condition.label }}" class="has-tip wi {{ block.condition }}"></span>
        {% elseif block.type == "temperature" %}
            <p class="post-temperature right">
            {{ block.degrees }}
            <sup>°C</sup></p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Just to be clear... you have a Matrix block called `condition` and a dropdown field type called `condition`?

Comment: I changed the Matrix block to "forecast" and the dropdown field remains "condition", albeit more readable now, I am unsure what to use for the title `{{,,,,,}}` field to produce the Option Label.